# Azure retiring Basic IP Address SKU, but can't create Basic site-to-site VPN with Standard IP SKU

Tags: azure, azure-vpn, azure-virtual-network-gateway

Azure is retiring "Basic" IP SKUs 9/30/2025. I've migrated all my IPs to Standard level now except for our site-to-site VPN. When I try to migrate it, it says it is allocated and in use, and thus can't be upgraded. No problem, Plan B.

I create a new IP, create a new VPN (Virtual Network Gateway) and when it asks for a level, I change the default VpnGw2AZ level back to Basic (read $357.70/month to $26.28/month)... and I chose the new IP I created. It throws the error: "Static Public IP Addresses cannot be associated"

Since Standard IP addresses are always Static (only Basic IP can be Dynamic)... apparently either this is an oversight by MS or MS is phasing out Basic VPN as well??? Forcing users who need it to start at least with VpnGwAZ1 which is $138.70/mo?

To be sure, I try to create a new IP in that interface and it only allows creation of a Basic IP if I have Basic VPN selected.

Am I missing something? I found this in an article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#how-does-the-retirement-of-basic-sku-public-ip-addresses-affect-my-vpn-gateways

> **How does the retirement of Basic SKU public IP addresses affect my VPN gateways?**
> We are taking action to ensure the continued operation of deployed VPN gateways that utilize Basic SKU public IP addresses. If you already have VPN gateways with Basic SKU public IP addresses, there is no need for you to take any action.

So I guess I table this for 18mo or so and wait to see what changes? What am I missing? Has anyone else figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

As per [MsDoc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/upgrade-to-standard-sku-public-ip-addresses-in-azure-by-30-september-2025-basic-sku-will-be-retired/?cdn=disable)  Basic SKU public IPs will be retired on September 30, 2025 all existing Basic IP addresses will need to be migrated to Standard IP addresses before this date.

> **There should be no immediate requirement for you to take any action if your VPN gateways currently have Basic SKU public IP addresses, as per Microsoft's announcement. For these deployments, Microsoft is probably developing a migration plan or finding substitutes.**

When I tried to create virtual network gateway with Basic public Ip I got the same error like below:

[image]

> ***Note*** that for Basic VPN gateway supported only dynamic public IP addresses.

Created Basic VPN gateway with dynamic public IP address like below:

[image]

[image]

If you want to use a static public IP address, you will need to use a Standard VPN gateway like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for documenting what I've already said. That's the point I'm making/asking though... They force you to use Standard IP (retire Basic IP) but you can't use Standard IP on Basic VPN anymore... so despite NOT announcing they are getting rid of Basic VPN ($26/mo), they are essentially doing so and forcing the lowest possible VPN price to have a ~6x price hike to VpnGW1AZ ($138/mo).

Comment: Basic SKU VPN gateways always used Basic Public IP address. You can't have a mixture of basic SKU resources and standard SKU resources. Refer this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/public-ip-addresses#ip-address-version). Hence you can only create Basic VPN gateways using Basic SKU Public IP. You can make use of Basic SKU VPN gateways until next Microsoft update.

Comment: I appreciate your discourse, but it isn't a solution. MS announced they are retiring Basic IP's... but not that they are retiring Basic VPN as well. So they are forcing users to take a 6x price hike to keep a VPN? I'm hoping the status of this will change in the next 18 months before Basic IP is discontinued.