# VPN Gateway "Basic" SKU replacement options?

Tags: azure-vpn, azure-virtual-network-gateway

As many have noticed, the "Basic" level SKU for VPNGW is [going away 9/2025](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/standard-and-highperformance-vpn-gateway-skus-will-be-retired-on-30-september-2025/). The [alternatives](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/vpn-gateway/) are 6x more expensive.  Perhaps my reasons for needing the basic VPNGW are obsolete... we can tackle that in another thread.  Can anyone suggest an alternative Azure VPN gateway service that is as inexpensive as Basic VPNGW?  My max spend is $25/month.  I never top more than 2kB/day in traffic.

I tried calling Azure network support. Never have I met a more confused bunch of people. They had no idea about the different VPNGW SKUs nor that the Basic one is sunsetting.  The only [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067702/azure-retiring-basic-ip-address-sku-but-cant-create-basic-site-to-site-vpn-wit) I found on this topic had no resolution so I'm bringing it up again.

Comment: Clear as mud.  Basic VPN is staying, but the Basic IP is going away. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#is-vpn-gateway-basic-sku-retiring-as-well